# How to update an XML File on Disk using c#

Tags: xml

I have an XML file with one well known node, call it Foo.

So somewhere in the XML file I have a framgment that looks like:

```
<Foo atr1="value1"/>
```

I want to change that to:

```
<Foo atr1="value1"/>  
<MyElement  .......>
   <MoreMystuff>
   </MoreMystuff>  
</MyElement>
```

and then it needs to be written back to the *same file* on disk.

What would be a good and quick way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

if i don't mistaken according to XML standart there can be only one root element so your code is

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("<root><Foo atr1=\"value1\"/></root>");
        /// or load from file as you want
        //doc.Load("pathTOfile.xml")

        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;


        XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("MyElement");
        elem.Attributes.Append(doc.CreateAttribute("atrib"));
        // Change the value of the first attribute.
        elem.SetAttribute("atrib", "val");
        XmlElement MoreStyffElem = doc.CreateElement("MoreStuff");
        elem.AppendChild(MoreStyffElem);

        doc.FirstChild.AppendChild(elem);
        Console.WriteLine("Display the modified XML...");
        Console.WriteLine(doc.InnerXml);
        //or save to file
        //doc.Save("theSameFileName.xml")
```

also this link must be usefull for you
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/y3y47afh.aspx